# How can i join a minecraft server that is not located within my local network

Tags: minecraft-java-edition

I have Minecraft for the pc, and wish to join my friends server however it is not located on the same local network as my computer is.

how can I join this server without moving to my friends local area network?

Comment: I believe the questioner is intending to ask how to connect to a server that is not hosted on their local area network.                                                                                                                      tho I can not answer this question due to the fact that it was flagged as a duplicate, I wish to provide that this can be done via network tunneling using hamachi as others have already stated or through means of obtaining the servers ip address and connecting that way.

Answer (score 1):

Both of you need to download Hamachi and create your own virtual network.  It's a great tool, easy to set up, and will do exactly what you want it to without you needing to host or rent your own server.

Just do a Google search for Hamachi.  The client is easy to download, set up, and configure.  There are other alternatives but I found this to be the easiest method before I just started hosting my own.

Answer (score 0):

Depending on how techy you are you could set up a VPN Tunneling system to your friends network.

Otherwise, LAN based worlds are...well...LAN based. Meaning, you must somehow be connected to your friends Local Area Network. A VPN Tunneling system is fairly easy to set up, basically resulting in your computer tunneled into your friends network system. This virtually works as though you had your computer at her house, and you should be able to join her LAN world.